# How to implement ActionListener

Tags: java, actionlistener

I am trying to simply change the value of a JLabel when a button is clicked.

This is the GUI code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class login extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
       public login (){

         //Create (Frame, Label, Text input for doctors name & Password field):

       JFrame frame = new JFrame("Doctor Login");
       JLabel label = new JLabel("Login Below:");
       JTextField name = new JTextField(10);
       JPasswordField pass = new JPasswordField(10);
       JButton button = new JButton("Login");

        //Exit program on close:
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

       //Label
       label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
       label.setLocation(100,100);

       //Add Elements to frame:
       frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       frame.getContentPane().add(label);
       frame.getContentPane().add(name);
       frame.getContentPane().add(pass);
       frame.getContentPane().add(button);

       //Create border for text field:
       Border nameBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1);

       name.setBorder(nameBorder);
       pass.setBorder(nameBorder);

       //Set Size of frame:
       frame.setSize(500, 250);

       //Set Location of the frame on the screen:
       frame.setLocation(200,200);

       //Display
       frame.setVisible(true);


       //Compiler Gives an error here - Illegal Start of Expression
       public void actionEvent(ActionEvent event){
           label.setText("Logged in");
       }
    }

}
```

main class code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Date;

public class main
{

public static void main(String[] args) {

   login login = new login();

}


}
```

The actionEvent method in the login class returns the error Illegal Start of Expression.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect; you either mean to use an anonymous class, or you mean to declare your `actionPerformed` as a class method but accidentally put that declaration in `login`. The example in the official [action listener tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) is almost identical to what you are trying to do here (it updates a label with the count of the number of times a button was clicked). You may want to have a read through it. I am voting to close this as a typographical error.

Comment: Adding to what has already been said, it's bad practice have a variable name that is the same as the class name. (`login login = new login();`).

By convention class names should start with an uppercase character.

To avoid confusion, change `login login = new login();` to `login log = new login();` or rename the class to '`Login`'.

Answer (score 4):

If you *just want to add the `ActionListener` to the button*, then you should delete

```
implements ActionListener
```

and do:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        label.setText(...);
    }
});
```

**Notes:**

- Note that you are getting that error because you are adding that method *inside* the constructor.
- You should follow Java naming conventions, use names like `SomeClass` for classes and `someVariable` for variables or methods.

Answer (score 2):

You've misplaced *and* misnamed the actionPerformed method. Right now you have it nested inside of the constructor, and Java does not allow methods to be nested inside of other methods or constructors (same for constructors not being allowed to be nested in methods or constructors). Move it out of the constructor, call it `actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)`, and see what happens.

Comment: If I move it out of the constructor I cannot access the label to change it?

Comment: @AnonOmus: simple solution then: declare the JLabel, and anything else that needs to be referenced from within the class into the class itself as an instance field.

Comment: Thanks I have just done that as it happens and it works, excuse my OOP ignorance

Comment: @AnonOmus: Not to worry as none of us was born knowing Java or OOPs, except perhaps you're [Jon Skeet](http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/my-favourite-jon-skeet-facts/). As an aside, it looks like what you really want to create with this code is a Login dialog that is displayed in a modal JDialog, not in a JFrame.

Comment: Wow - "Jon Skeet can make IE obey his CSS rules.", He MUST be a genius then.

Comment: @AnonOmus: indeed. He's the highest ranking member of StackOverflow as far as I understand it, and as per [this link](http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow/2014-03-16?sort=totalreputation).

Comment: The 360 knowledge of web dev/programming alot of users on here seem to have is amazing, and a little intimidating.